# Find attributes with prefix attribute name

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have html look likes :

```
<div in-prop in-alias="" in-type="teacher"><div in-name="Alice">Hello <i in-name="Wonderland">World</i></div></div>
```

I want to collect custom attribute names based on prefix `in-` attribute name, I have working code and returns `["prop", "alias", "type", "name", "name"]`

```
require 'nokogiri'

class PartB
  def get_scheme(html)
    get_doc(html).map { |elm|
      elm.attributes.map{|k, v| k.gsub("in-", "") if !k.nil? && k.include?("in-")}
    }.flatten.compact
  end

  def get_doc(html)
    Nokogiri::HTML(html).search('*')
  end
end
```

but I think that is redundant, because I use `search('*')` and it will get all html tags. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<div in-prop in-alias="" in-type="teacher"><div in-name="Alice">Hello <i in-name="Wonderland">World</i></div></div>')

a = doc.xpath("//@*[starts-with(name(), 'in')]")

a.map { |i| i.name[3..-1] }  # => ["prop", "alias", "type", "name", "name"]
```